# In git, editing a historical pre-pull commit after the pull causes divergence from origin

Tags: git, rebase

In the following scenario:

1. Make commits A, B, C
2. Pull, getting commits D, E
3. Make more commits F, G, H, ...
4. Realize that you need to tweak B
5. Tweak B using `git rebase -i` and `git commit --amend`

Now `git status` says:

```
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged.
```

How should I fix this?

**Note**: I did not push; this has nothing to do with pushing.

**Note**: Simply pulling again does not fix the problem; it just re-merges the commits D, E on top of what I already have (despite the D, E already being there in the history), which also has the side-effect of producing superfluous conflicts.

To elaborate, one answer below suggests that the history now is:

```
- A - B' - C' - F' - G' - H' (master)
\
 D - E (origin/master)
```

This isn't quite right - it's actually:

```
- A - B' - C' - D(?) - E(?) - F' - G' - H' (master)
\
 D - E (origin/master)
```

Hence, my problem. I'd like it to be:

```
- A - B' - C' - F' - G' - H' (master)
\         /
 D - E (origin/master)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I won't accept my own answer for a while because I'm genuinely curious about other (better) approaches.

The way I got out of this was hardly elegant:

```
# stash F, G, H - can't simply reorder them before D, E since they depend a lot on D, E
for i in {1..3}; do git reset HEAD^; git stash; done
# wipe out the weird non-merge D and E commits
git reset --hard HEAD~2
# pull to merge D, E again
git pull
# restore F, G, H
for i in {1..3}; do git stash pop; git commit -a; done
```

Comment: You said in your comment to my answer that D and E were already in the history, but here you imply they aren't. But in your other comment, you also implied that you were using `pull --rebase`, which would mean that your pull here isn't actually merging. I'm happy to try and find you a better answer, and I'm sure there is one - if this worked, it sounds like all you have to do is checkout, re-pull, rebase. But I need to know exactly what the history looks like to give a good answer, and I'm not too confident I know right now.

Comment: @Jefromi `pull --rebase` isn't being used. D and E are in the history, which I wiped out with the second line. I think what you're suggesting is a better way to get at what I did above, so please do enlighten me!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you didn't use the `-p` option to git rebase, which means that the pull you did, merging commits D and E, was wiped away. If that's all that's happened, this is simple: just pull again. If this is what happened, your history will look like this:

```
- A - B' - C' - F' - G' - H' (master)
\
 D - E (origin/master)
```

There's your divergence!

If you *did* preserve the merge, then quite possibly this is just because something new was pushed to origin in the meantime:

```
- A - B' - C' - X' - F' - G' - H' (master)
\              /
 D - E -------- - Z (origin/master)
```

and so the solution, again, would be to pull.

If, however, you pushed something containing the original commit B, then you shouldn't have rebased. This will *always* cause divergence, and it's not a fun kind. Your history would look like this:

```
    B' - C' - F' - G' - H' (master)
   /
- A - B - C - X - F - G - H (origin/master)
\            /
 D - E ------
```

It's a fundamental fact of git's design that the SHA1 of a commit depends on the SHA1 of its parent, and therefore on the entire ancestry chain. This is why after the rebases, I've put a "prime" on everything. Even if you haven't modified C's content, the commit is modified. (The other possibility, that you preserved the merge, and pushed, should ve inferrable as a combination of the last two pictures.)

Comment: +1, and "not fun" indeed, as detailed in the paragraph " [RECOVERING FROM UPSTREAM REBASE](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase) " from the [`git rebase` man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html)...

Comment: Simply pulling again does not fix the problem; it just reapplies the commits D, E on top of what I already have (despite the D, E already being there in the history), which also has the side-effect of producing superfluous conflicts. You're right in that I didn't use `-p`; I'm interested in repairing the status quo given that I didn't use `-p`. Also, I never pushed.

Comment: @Yang: "it just reapplies the commits D, E on top of what I already have" meaning you have pull set up to rebase instead of merge? That's highly relevant information, and as the manpage says: "This is a potentially dangerous mode of operation... Do not use this option unless you have read git-rebase(1) carefully."

Comment: No, my pulls merge; they don't rebase. I should've phrased that differently, as "it just re-merges D, E in with what I already have."